# SBT how to import geotools dependencies

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm new to scala and sbt. I'm trying to add a managed dependency to my scala project in Intellij, and the build phase finishes successfully, but I'm not able to reach any geotools class in my code, my build.sbt file look like this:

```
name := "somename"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.13.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.geotools" % "gt-main" % "20.4" from "https://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main",
  "org.geotools" % "gt-epsg-hsql" % "20.4" from "https://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main",
  "org.geotools" % "gt-metadata" % "20.4" from "https://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main",
  "org.geotools" % "gt-referencing" % "20.4" from "https://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main",

)
```

Used same dependencies set in pure java/maven project works fine. Have anyone faced similar problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems it is on [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools/gt-main/22-RC) so I guess you only need to declare them and reload.

Comment: Try to *reimport* the sbt build file. There's an action called `Reimport all gradle/sbt/bsp projects" in IntelliJ. Try this.